# Cross-version compatibility of Berkley DB files

Tags: compatibility, berkeley-db

Legacy app uses Berkeley DB 4.8.
Due to some reasons app has been compiled with newer Berkeley DB lib (I want to use 5.1 or 6.1).

Whether the new app still compatible with the database files generated by old version of the app?
If not - where I can find info about compatibility of different versions of the lib and database files?

Answer (score 2):

BerkeleyDB is always backward compatible (i.e. new version can read data files of old version).

OTOH, the transactional log format changes with nearly every release, and the version is embedded in the __db.00* dbenv files, so be forewarned: the compatibility isn't entirely transparent. Both the dbenv and logs are pretty easily regenerated.

There is also a db_upgrade(8) utility (but I have never used).

All changes between versions (including format changes) are described in the online BerkeleyDB manual at Oracle.